# import image in python, my program cant work if i move program folder in different place if I want it to run, I have to change my code

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

i have problem on my program, I import images, and it works but behind that success there is something missing for me.
Check out the following code snippet:

```
# python 3
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk

pathdesign_img = "D:/Python/Project1/image/design/

self.logo_Tbar_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(pathdesign_img+'Mlogo.jpg'))
self.logo_Tbar = tk.Label(self.bar_Tbar, image=self.logo_Tbar_img, bg="#DA291C")
self.logo_Tbar.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH)
```

The code works but when I want to move all my program folders to diffrent place example: `C:\User\`. My program cannot run and if I want it to run, I have to change `pathdesign_img = "C:/User/...."`. Is there any code that I need to change or add, so that my program can run in any folder, without having to change `pathdesign_img`

Comment: Try making the path relative instead of absolute

Comment: Post the error traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, paths relative to your app's directory are the correct solution, but when passing them forward to be used it is always advisable to use absolute paths.
So, you use absolute paths relative to your app's directory.

It can be easy as:

```
import os

dirpath   = os.path.abspath("images")
# os.path.abspath() will return the absolute path of the directory images
# that resides in the current working directory which you can discover with
# os.getcwd() and manipulate using os.chdir()
# Note that the current working directory may be manipulated from the OS.
# In the Windows's case you can specify it under properties of the shortcut
# and/or the executable. By the default it is the same directory where
# the executable lives, in this case, your script.
imagepath = os.path.join(dirpath, "<some_image>.jpg")
```

That is how it should be done. It is cross-platform, good practice, and will not give you trouble with paths.

However, if you are planning to bundle your app into a e.g. EXE, you need to be much craftier than that. That's because the *.exe bundled app is actually a ZIP file with some additions.
In this case the imagepath will look like:

```
>>> print (imagepath)
C:\Program Files\Yours_app_folder\yourapp.exe\images\your_image.jpg
```

which, of course is an invalid path for the OS. In these cases I do the following.
I create a module called whereiam or whereami (the name depends on how I feel I guess) in which I put a var or function that gets me the correct path to my app's directory. E.g.

```
import os, sys

def root ():
    # If the app is only a script, this will result in mydir
    # being a path to the directory where the 'whereiam' module lives:
    me = os.path.abspath(__file__)
    mydir = os.path.dirname(me)
    # If the app is bundled then sys.executable points to it instead
    # of Python interpreter, so first check for that
    if mydir.startswith(sys.executable):
        # Then we first get the directory where our app lives:
        mydir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
        # And if our whereiam is in a subdirectory, we find it by excluding
        # the executable's filename from the path:
        # by appending the rest to the mydir
        l = len(sys.executable)
        mydir = os.path.join(mydir.rstrip(os.sep), me[l:].lstrip(os.sep))
    return mydir
```

Then in your main module you just do:

```
import whereiam
import os

dirpath   = whereiam.root()
images    = os.path.join(dirpath, "images")
imagepath = os.path.join(images, "<your_image>.jpg")
# And you can then open imagepath with PIL or whatever being sure that it will be found if it is there
```

Comment: if using pyinstaller, you can use the `sys._MEIPASS` folder when extracting media files from an executable. Like so: `media_path = os.path.join(getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), '' if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) else 'media\\')`

Comment: @oskros : Useful info, but I, for one, use py2exe and am not a fan of pyinstaller because it is buggy and building something more complicated ends with frustrations instead with working executable. The second point, if I understood you correctly, you are refering to finding the folder inside of an executable, or am I mistaken??? Because I usually prefer putting media outside of it. It loads faster, can be changed without building a new .exe each time and so on.

Comment: @KisahTegar : You are welcome, but don't thank people on SO. If a Q makes sense, it's our "job" to help you. Thanks are expressed using votes. It's just that we do not want comments to be cluttered with thankses of all kind.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be possible. I assume that your python-file or jupyter-notebook is in the folder "D:/Python/Project1", whereas your image is in the folder "D:/Python/Project1/image/design". Then you could do:

```
pathdesign_img = "image/design/"
```

In short, what this does: In the folder that you are already in, it searches for a folder called "image" and in that folder for a sub-folder called "design".

Comment: Having "/" at the beginning of a path means that it is absolute path, not relative path.

Comment: Thanks guys love you all :)